# Checking values in dicts and deleting if condition met in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have JSON objects where there are values of None and I would like to remove any dictionary that maintains these values.  How do I successfully implement logic which removes the dictionary if my conditional statement is met?

```
 {
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
                "BulkyItem": [
                    {
                        "BulkyItemCount": "None", 
                        "BulkyItemType": "None", 
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "072420150115103541", 
                        "Type": "Bulky Items"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "BulkyItemCount": "None", 
                        "BulkyItemType": "None", 
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "072420150115103542", 
                        "Type": "Bulky Items"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": "", 
            "ResolutionCode": "A", 
            "SRNumber": "1-21939511"
        }
    }
```

`D` in the code below refers to the dictionaries in the BulkyItem list.

```
lIndexes = []
            nCnt = len(l311)
            for i in range(nCnt):
                dd = l311[i]
                if(dd==d):
                    lIndexes.append(i)

            for i in lIndexes:
                i

            #remove the d from the original l311 in a reverse order:
            # print ("order (of index) in which items are deleted:" )
            for ii in reversed(lIndexes):
               if d['Name'] <> str:
                    # print(ii)
                    del l311[ii]
```

Output JSON using @Ewan's suggested syntax.

```
[
    {
        "MetaData": {}, 
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {
                "La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": [
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "HouseHoldItemCount": "None", 
                        "HouseholdItem": "None", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": "072820151331438211", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA", 
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                        "ElectronicWestType": "None", 
                        "ItemCount": "None", 
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                        "Name": " ", 
                        "Type": "Metal/Household Appliances"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            "ReasonCode": "", 
            "ResolutionCode": "", 
            "SRNumber": "1-22184611"
        }
    }
]
```

Code works aside from last dictionary appending, what could cause this?

Comment: Just to get you right, you want to filter a list (`BulkyItem`) of dictionaries and drop those which contain `None` in `d["BulkyItemCount"]`?

Comment: when `a` is your datastructure `filter(lambda x: x["BulkyItemCount"] not in ["None", None, ""], a["SRData"]["ListOfLa311BulkyItem"]["BulkyItem"])` .. hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: @synner that is correct.

Comment: @Synner, what do you mean when you say a is my data structure?

Comment: I mean your json is in `a`, I pass it as the second parameter to `filter` accessing the inner list of the JSON

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `None` in your JSON is a string and not the `None` type.

So you will need to modify your check to be:

```
if d["BulkyItemCount"] == None or d["BulkyItemCount"] == "None"
```

Comment: This does not work either, the dictionaries with None values remain.

Comment: What did your print(ii) report before you commented it out? Try print (l311(ii)) to see what it prints

Comment: @Dan Patterson, print (ii) prints the reverse order at which dictionaries would be removed, starting at 9. 9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2

Comment: @Ewan, the latter works, however one dictionary is being appended at the end of my list.  Please see update.  What could cause this?

Comment: @geoffreyGIS - what do you mean last dictionary appending? there's no empty dict there I presume this is to do with your data source?